# How can I input ctrl+` (grave accent)?

Tags: macos, keyboard

Normally when typing `` ` ``, I have to hold shift down and press `´`, and a "dead" version of the grave accent appears. I then have to press space to get the "living" version of the grave accent.

You can see here what I mean by living and dead ([dead keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Dead_keys)):

[image: Screenshot]

If I want to open the console in Sublime Text 2, I can use the menu bar to open it, however, I would rather use the keyboard shortcut ctrl+`

Neither using ctrl+shift+´ or ctrl+´ works.

How would I input this keyboard shortcut?

**Note:** I already know that you can edit the keyboard shortcut for the menu item in System Preferences, but I have seen other applications also requiring keyboard shortcuts I can't input using my keyboard layout (Danish).

I don't want to change my keyboard layout either, not even temporary.

Answer (score 2):

Some keyboard layouts (like Finnish, but not Danish) have a normal backtick under ⌥⇧´, so for example ⌃⌥⇧´ opens the console in Sublime Text.

If you don't want to switch to another keyboard layout, you can use Ukelele to modify the Danish layout. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/257199/arbitrary-key-remapping-on-a-mac/257566#257566).